# Laravel 8 doesn't update a sessions but creates a new one on each request

Tags: laravel-8

this question has been asked a couple of times but it seems that no one has been able to solve it for real i.e. "it works on remote", "problem solved by changing 'file' to 'cookie'" etc. etc. but after 2 days (I'm still new to Laravel) of try & error still not able to fix this...

**A - the setup:**

1. from scratch installed Laravel 8.36.2 via `laravel new designs --jet` on a Mac running OS X 10.15.7
2. installed debug bar via `composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev`
3. running on a local `brew install httpd` installation of Apache/2.4.46
4. MySQL Ver 8.0.23 for osx10.15 on x86_64 (Homebrew as well)
5. accessing the application via designs.test (domain pointing to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts)

**B - Laravel config:**

`.env`

```
    APP_NAME=Designs
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_URL=http://www.designs.test
    APP_STATIC_URL=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

    LOG_CHANNEL=stack
    LOG_LEVEL=debug

    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    DB_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

    BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
    CACHE_DRIVER=file
    QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
    SESSION_DRIVER=database
    SESSION_LIFETIME=120

    MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

    REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
    REDIS_PASSWORD=null
    REDIS_PORT=6379

    MAIL_MAILER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=mailhog
    MAIL_PORT=1025
    MAIL_USERNAME=null
    MAIL_PASSWORD=null
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
    MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
    AWS_BUCKET=

    PUSHER_APP_ID=
    PUSHER_APP_KEY=
    PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
    PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

    MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
    MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

`app/config/app.php`

```
    // Application Name
    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Designs'),

    // Application Environment
    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'development'),

    // Application Debug Mode
    'debug' => (bool) env('APP_DEBUG', true),

    // Application URL
    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://www.designs.test'),
    'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),

    // Application Timezone
    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    //Application Locale Configuration
    'locale' => 'en',

    // Application Fallback Locale
    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    // Faker Locale
    'faker_locale' => 'en_US',

    // Encryption Key
    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),
    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    // Autoloaded Service Providers
    'providers' => [
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\JetstreamServiceProvider::class,
    ],

    // Class Aliases
    'aliases' => [
        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Arr' => Illuminate\Support\Arr::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'Date' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Date::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Http' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        // 'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    ],
```

`app/config/session.php`

```
    // Default Session Driver
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),

    // Session Lifetime
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    // Session Encryption
    'encrypt' => false,

    //Session File Location
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    // Session Database Connection
    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

    // Session Database Table
    'table' => 'sessions',

    // Session Cache Store
    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

    // Session Sweeping Lottery
    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    // Session Cookie Name
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    // Session Cookie Path
    'path' => '/',

    // Session Cookie Domain
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'localhost.com'),

    // HTTPS Only Cookies
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

    // HTTP Access Only
    'http_only' => true,

    // Same-Site Cookies
    'same_site' => 'lax',
```

`routes/web.php`

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

    // Web Routes
    Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'test']);
```

`app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php`

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class HomeController extends Controller {
    
        public function test() {
            return view('empty');
        }
    
    }
```

**VIEWS & Layouts**

`resources/views/layouts/boilerplate.blade.php`

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap">
            <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

            <title>Document Title</title>
        </head>
    
        <body>
            @yield('content')
        </body>

    </html>
```

`resources/views/empty.blade.php`

```
    @extends('layouts.boilerplate')
    @section('content')
        <p>This is my body content.</p>
    @endsection
```

## **THE PROBLEM**

each time you access the / route (i.e. reload the page after a second or two), Laravel will generate a new Session in the DB:
[image: first request]
[image: second request after a few seconds]

The problem get's really big if you going to request some data via an AJAX call to the same domain API and provide the token to compare it on the backend - Laravel will generate a new session as well as a new token and return a mismatch of the provided with `'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')`

## **QUESTION**

WHAT THE HELL AM I MISSING?!? Any help highly ... **HIGHLY** appreciated and I'm more then willing to write a "how-to" for all the others that face the same problem and there are a few...

Comment: Hey did you ever come to a solution by any chance? I'm having the same issue on a production app.